# How to statically link DLLs and LIBs in VC++ Windows Form Application?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, static-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am able to build my Windows Forms (32 bit) project in VC++ 2008. When I build a setup and try to run it on another system, it gives the error

> Application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is
>   incorrect.

I searched a lot for a solution and then tried to install the exact version on VC++ 2008 redistributable x86. But the problem is still same.

I tried to change the properties of the project from Dynamic link to static link, but this generated the error

> "/Mtd" and "/clr:pure" command line argument is incorrect.

I was thinking if there is any way to combine the DLLs and LIBs with the application itself?
Or is there any other way?

Comment: You are deploying the Debug build of your project, that can't work.  Deploy the Release build instead.